# Port-forwarding HTTPS web server

Tags: ssl, https, port-forwarding

I have port forwarded our front-facing IP to an internal HTTPS server. The browser does not connect. A `wget` command determines that the certificate is self-signed for the internal IP. Hence why the browser is refusing to display the page properly. What is the best-practice scenario for this sort of stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is just pure port forwarding then the firewall/router shouldn't need to touch the data, so clearly you're doing something else here.

If you want to leave it modifying the requests then you'll need to put the ssl certificate on the firewall.  Otherwise you'll want to stop it modifying the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Install the port forwarder's certificate as an authority in the browser.  This will let browsers verify that they're talking to someone you trust.  Meanwhile, hopefully the port forwarder performs its own verification of certificates on the outgoing SSL connections it establishes.